# How to assign string names to values in dictionary

Tags: python

I am working on resume parser and my spacy model was trained with lables 1.0 is for "skills",2.0: ;"hobbies" etc..., now, after predicting the model i have the below output with same lables.. However, i want to assign like if 1.0--> "Skills", 2.0-->"hobbies" in python. Please advise how can we assign. I want output to be in json format.

````
        predicted = cv_sections_model.predict((text))
        # print("raw text", predicted)
        predicted_sections = [zipped for zipped in zip(text, predicted)]
        return predicted_sections.
output : 
[('  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564', 1.0),('  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564', 1.0)]```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can have a dictionary structure that saves the information like:

```
dictionary = {1.0: "Skills", 2.0: "Hobbies"}
```

Now in your predicted, you can have a loop that makes a new list

```
predict_names = []
for i in predicted:
   predict_names.append(dictionary[i])
```

Comment: ```output = model_output(file_path)

print(res,output)
dictionary = {
    1.0: "personal_info",
    2.0: "personal_statement",
    3.0: "experience",
    4.0: "skills",
    5.0: "education",
    6.0: "hobbies",}

predict_names = []
for i in output:
   predict_names.append(dictionary[i][0])
   
print(predict_names)``` I am facing the below key error : ```output = model_output(file_path)

print(res,output)
dictionary = {
    1.0: "personal_info",
    2.0: "personal_statement",
    3.0: "experience",
    4.0: "skills",
    5.0: "education",
    6.0: "hobbies",}
```

Comment: predict_names.append(dictionary[i][0])
KeyError: (1.0, '  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564')

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is a simple mapping which can be done using the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) function.

```py
labels = [1.0, 2.0]

mapping = {
    1.0: "Skills",
    2.0: "Hobbies"
}

# lookup desired value for a given label
mapping_func = lambda label: mapping[label]

mapped = list(map(mapping_func, labels))

print("Before mapping:\t", labels)
print("After mapping:\t", mapped)
```

Expected output

```py
Before mapping:  [1.0, 2.0]
After mapping:   ['Skills', 'Hobbies']
```

### Edit

You can apply this idea to your output array as well. There are mainly two routes (or actually one route but the order of steps is flipped) which you can take that will will give you the same result, only that approach `#1` is simpler to my mind.

```py
# assumption: this is what you feed your model
texts = ('  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564', '  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564')
# predicted = model.predict(texts)
# that is what your model predicts
predicted = [1.0, 2.0]

# define mapping
mapping = {
    1.0: "Skills",
    2.0: "Hobbies"
}

# Two ways to handle this
#----------
# 1. My preferred option
#----------
# first map the labels to the corresponding text
mapped_labels_1 = map(lambda label: mapping[label], predicted)
# then use zip to get the output
output_1 = list(zip(texts, mapped_labels_1))
print("1. Option:", output_1)

#----------
# 2.
#----------
# zip first
predicted_result = zip(texts, predicted)
# now map(): but input for the lambda is now a tuple not a single value!
mapping_func = lambda output_tuple: (output_tuple[0], mapping[output_tuple[1]])
output_2 = list(map(mapping_func, predicted_result))

print("2. Option:", output_2)
```

Expected output

```
1. Option: [('  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564', 'Skills'), ('  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564', 'Hobbies')]
2. Option: [('  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564', 'Skills'), ('  Contact Number: +91- 7810135564', 'Hobbies')]
```

Comment: thanks, but where i should be giving model output here?

Comment: I have now edited my answer to include how you would combine your `input` for the model with the predicted `labels` mapped to their corresponding texts, if that was what you wanted.

Comment: my model output will be list of tuples  ```output = [(1.0, ' Contact Number: +91- 7810135564'),[(2.0, '  Good knowledge in software development'),( , "string").....]. ```With the below code i am facing key error. Please help..

Comment: Did you take approach `#1` or `#2`? If you chose `#2`, it is probably because you have the `float` value first then the `string` in your tuple and I did it the other way round. In order to adjust for that, change the lambda function to `lambda output_tuple: (mapping[output_tuple[0]], output_tuple[1])`. Another possibility could be that you have values in there that have not declared a mapping. You need to declare a mapping for all values or use a function instead that checks whether a mapping is defined and if not it returns some default value which you also need to define. Many options there.